# How to clone StackOverFlow JQuery Interface?

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, interface

Is there any opensource samples of JQuery usages of StackOverFlow-like sites......

Any help in this direction??

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, I'm not quite sure what you're asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the same effects by using [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/).

- http://www.jqueryplugins.com/
- http://www.sastgroup.com/jquery/240-plugins-jquery

Comment: Yes, JQuery Plugin Architecture makes this way pretty convenient. 

Are there any JQuery plugins that covers 

- Voting
- Tags
- Editing (Community wiki style)
- Badges

Comment: voting, tags and badges are made on ajax, which supported by jQuery. For WYSIWYG editing you can use this plugin - http://livepipe.net/control/textarea , looks the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816691/list-of-jquery-plugins-that-can-be-used-to-clone-stackoverflow-interface

Answer (score 3):

The web is full of them. For starters, I recommend reading through the [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

It could help if everybody would just make a list of the plugins that are being used. For example, for plotting they use: [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). For flot support on IE you need [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)... I kind of feel this question has been answered before though...